# jQuery run function after $.each ajax request has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I had a simple script working using `Promises` in ECMA6 but I'm now converting what I wrote to jQuery to be compatible for all browsers but the issue I'm having is that `availableDevices` contains an array of AJAX responses rather an array of product names like the script is telling it to.

Basically when all AJAX requests inside $.each have finished, I need to run a function with that data. What am I missing? (It's been a while since I wrote anything with jQuery...)

```
var availableDevices = [];

$.each(products, function (index, product) {

    availableDevices.push($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=' + formatProductName(product.product_name),
        complete: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                return formatProductName(product.product_name);
            }
        }
    }));

});

$.when(availableDevices).then(function (data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: Try: `$.when.apply($, availableDevices).then`

Comment: Note that it should be `$.when.apply($, availableDevices)...`. Also, the `then` handler will not receive any data. You would need to deal with that in the `complete` handler of each AJAX request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How do I make it receive data?

Comment: Is the data you need returned in each AJAX request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The AJAX request is a simple availability checker and the data received from the API will either be a 1 (available) or 0 (unavailable) but a product will only be unavailable if the product being searched for doesn't actually exist in the API (404) so that's why I'm using the response status (200) to return the product name for available products. I want to make an array of available products and use this further down the line. (In $.when)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to store the result of each call inside a separate array, you have access to each response via the `then` method:

```
var requests = [];
$.each(products, function (index, product) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=' + formatProductName(product.product_name)        
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
    console.log(arguments.length + " results returned");
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        var arg = arguments[i];
       console.log(arg);   
    }
});
```

Live example (using jsfiddle json echo for demo): http://jsfiddle.net/vzq4Lwm8/

---

Having read your comment, there is a better solution, using a combination of `$.Deferred()` and the `complete` function on an `$.ajax` call:

```
var deferreds = $.map(products, function (product) {
    var formattedProduct = formatProductName(product)
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=' + formattedProduct,
        complete: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                defer.resolve(formattedProduct);
            }
            else{
                defer.resolve(null);
            }
        }
    })
    return defer;
});


$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
    console.log(arguments.length + " results returned");
    var availableProducts = $.map(arguments, function(x) { return x });
    // availableProducts will only contain items which returned 200 response
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vzq4Lwm8/1/

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment, this is what I'm after doing: The AJAX request is a simple availability checker and the data received from the API will either be a 1 (available) or 0 (unavailable) but a product will only be unavailable if the product being searched for doesn't actually exist in the API (404) so that's why I'm using the response status (200) to return the product name for available products. I want to make an array of ONLY available products and use this further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `$.when` doesn't have the correct syntax as you're providing an array to it. Also, when using this pattern you will have to merge all the responses together and use that in the `then()` handler. Something like this:

```
var requests = [];
var data = [];

$.each(products, function (index, product) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=' + formatProductName(product.product_name),
        success: function (response) {
            // note you're not actually using the `response` var here at all...?
            return data.push(formatProductName(product.product_name));
        }
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, availableDevices).then(function() {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) imply that you can get the data from each ajax call. I didnt think you needed to have a separate array for `data`. Also the OP *did* use the response (status)

Comment: @Jamiec that's true, if you know exactly how many promises will be in the array, and therefore how many params to provide the handler function. It may work for the OP, although I left it generic in this example.

Comment: I'm following this approach but console.log(data); (or console.log('anything'), just isn't being fired?

Comment: @leaksterrr have you checked the network tab of the console to ensure your AJAX requests are being made successfully?

Answer (score -2):

jQuery `$.ajax()` can use a parameter which is `success` that calls a function when the `ajax` request has finished successfully, as you can see in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So your code should be:

```
$.each(products, function (index, product) {

    availableDevices.push($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=' + formatProductName(product.product_name),
        complete: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                return formatProductName(product.product_name);
            }
        },
        success:function(){ }
    }));

});
```